# Why does ember.run call finish before work scheduled by ember.run.later completes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

According to the docs for [Ember.run](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) it:

> Runs the passed target and method inside of a RunLoop, ensuring any
>   deferred actions including bindings and views updates are flushed at
>   the end.

and so I expected that when I use it in a test, if the code under test were to schedule some work for later using [Ember.run.later](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later) that it should complete before the Ember.run call finishes, but that appears not to be so:

```
test('Ember.run waits for all scheduled actions to finish', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);
  var done = assert.async();
  let isRunLaterThingFinished = false;
  Ember.run(function() {
    Ember.run.later(function() {
      isRunLaterThingFinished = true;
      assert.ok(true, 'the scheduled thing happened');
      done();
    }, 1);
  });
  assert.ok(isRunLaterThingFinished, "scheduled actions should have happened by the time ember run finishes");
});
```

Which results in:

```
Ember.run waits for all scheduled actions to finish 
1. scheduled actions should have happened by the time ember run finishes
Expected:  true 
Result:    false
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here, and how I can have my tests wait for all of the scheduled methods to finish before doing my asserts?

Comment: I found a resource which is proving rather enlightening to my understanding of ember runloops: https://github.com/eoinkelly/ember-runloop-handbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.run.later` will create a separate run loop.
What you need to use is `Ember.run.schedule`.

```
  Ember.run(function() {
    Ember.run.schedule('actions', this, function() {
      // The code goes here
    });
  });
```

This way your function gets in the `actions` queue of the current run loop and will be executed before the end of the loop when the queue is flushed.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but what if I really want it to run later, like several seconds from now?

Comment: well, then you should not have any problem with it running in a separate run loop

Comment: Sorry, I mean if I want to have my test wait until it's done.  Is there a way to make my test wait for all of the run loops to finish their work?

Comment: looks like something like this may be the answer for getting my tests to wait: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/23/testing-asynchronous-behavior-ember/